# проблема с обращением к переменной в условиях SetText(умножение строкового ресурса)

Tags: java, android

При эмулировании выбивает программу, хотя среда разработки ошибку не выдает.

```
  @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int parse_kolichestvo = Integer.parseInt(tvResult.getText().toString());
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioButton_250:
                    cena.setText(getString(**R.string.cena53*parse_kolichestvo**));
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton_500:
                    cena.setText(getString(**R.string.cena73*parse_kolichestvo**));
                    break;
            }

        }
    });
```

Проблема именно в части умножения и обращения к строке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в вашем коде пытаетесь сделать нечто странное... А именно перемножить ID строкового ресурса, кое генерируется системой при каждом билде проекта и служит лишь для находжения строки с числом. Видимо вам надо:

1. Получить строку по её ID
2. Преобразовать строку в число
3. Перемножить числа
4. Полученное число преобразовать в строку

   ```
   cena.setText(String.valueof(Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.cena73))*parse_kolichestvo)));`
   ```

Comment: `getString(R.string.cena73))*parse_kolichestvo)` строку умножаем на int

Comment: и зачем цену в строке хранить...

Comment: @pavel, сие тайна великая есть)

Comment: Хлопцы, спасибо)